# Arduino's "Stream" equivalent to be used on ODroid

Tags: c++, arduino, stream, serial-port

I'm trying to edit [code](https://github.com/alexmos/sbgc-api-examples) that was written for Arduino to be used on ODroid-XU4. I was able to modify all the needed parts but I'm stuck at finding the equivalent for "Stream" class. 
Following are two snippets of code in the project where Stream was used.

```
/* Defines serial port routines required for SBGC_parser, here */
class ArduinoComObj : public SBGC_ComObj {
    Serial *serial;
    public:
    inline void init(Stream *s) {
        serial = s;
    }
    ...
}
...
// Prepare hardware, used in examples
void SBGC_Demo_setup(Stream *serial) {
  com_obj.init(serial);
  sbgc_parser.init(&com_obj);
}
```

And here is how these lines were used in the main file

```
#define SERIAL_SPEED 115200
#define serial Serial

void setup() {
    serial.begin(SERIAL_SPEED);  
    SBGC_Demo_setup(&serial);
}
```

Could anyone please explain to me how can I write an equivalent code to run on ODroid?

Comment: *How* do you want to "edit" the code? *Why* do you want to "edit" the code? What is the actual problem you want to solve by this "editing"? Perhaps you should try to reimplement what the program *does* instead of a straight (more or less) copy?

Comment: This code was written for Arduino and I'm not using Arduino. I'm using ODroid. I didn't programmed Arduino before but I think it has special libraries that are built specifically for Arduino, am I right? This project uses these libraries. By editing, I mean changing the parts of code that uses Arduino's libraries to use mine.
This project have examples for using SBGC libraries and I want to use these libraries in my project.

Comment: The ODroid-XU4 seems to be a "normal PC" in every respect, running a normal Linux distribution. Therefore there are no special embedded frameworks or classes to use. You program normal C++, targeting normal Linux. Which is why you should probably take a look at what the Arduino program is *doing* and reimplement that using normal standard C++ and Linux system calls, not try to do a straight one-to-one translation of the code.

Comment: Dude, Thanks for your help. I'm trying to follow your advice now. Thanks

Comment: I managed to solve my problem. As you said, it didn't require one-to-one translation. Should I delete the question as it doesn't like a good question?